# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to read from a txt File

Tags: java, arrays, file, linked-list

I am trying to read from a text file using java, the file called **student_file.txt** contains data about students like israa,gaza,1,99,32 with the following schema: name, address,id,grades,age
I split their data by comma using split() method and finally store them in linked list, but when I am trying to call **readStudentsFromFile()** mehtod it give me the following error:
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1**
code:

```java
private static void readStudentsFromFile() throws IOException {

        String file_name = "/Users/noor/NetBeansProjects/student_file.txt";
        BufferedReader reader;

        try {

            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_name));
            //String line = reader.readLine();
            String[] studentInfo;

            while (reader.readLine() != null) {

                studentInfo = reader.readLine().split(",");
                Student student = new Student(studentInfo[0], studentInfo[1], Integer.parseInt(studentInfo[2]), Integer.parseInt(studentInfo[3]), Integer.parseInt(studentInfo[4]));
                students.add(student); //add student to students linked list
                

            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("exception occurred" + e);

        }
    }
```

I am trying to read from a text file using java, the file contains information about a student, and I wanna store them as a Student object in Linked List so I can update, delete or search for them.

Comment: Do you have an empty line in your file? Check the length of your array before accessing it.

Comment: I noticed in your schema, **grades** is plural. Is this an array of some data type within the **Student** class that is to hold multiple grades?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is intentional because I don't know what your data file actually looks like, but the way your `while` loop is set up, your only processing every second file line. The `while` loop condition right away reads a file line upon each iteration

```
while (reader.readLine() != null) {
```

then another line is read in to actually get split:

```
studentInfo = reader.readLine().split(",");
```

On each iteration, it will actually be the second line that gets processed and added to the **LinkedList**. Like I said however, I'm not sure if you are doing this intentionally. If not a usual way would be something like this:

```
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.trim();  // Trim Leading/Trailing spacing 
    
    // Skip Blank Lines:
    if (line.isEmpty()) {
        continue;
    }
    // Split the line. The regex handles any delimiter spacing situations (if any):
    studentInfo = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");

    // ...  The rest of loop code ...
}
```

All in all, you could have something like this (read comments in code):

```
// Class member variable:
LinkedList<Student> students = new LinkedList<>();

private void readStudentsFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    /* 'Try With resouces' used here to auto-close file and free resources.
       This will read ANSI or UTF-8 created files.        */
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), "UTF-8"))) {
        String[] studentInfo;
        String line;
        
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.trim();   // Trim Leading/Trailing spacing 
            
            // Skip Blank Lines:
            if (line.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            
            // Split the line. The regex handles any delimiter spacing situations (if any):
            studentInfo = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");

            /* Verify Data - Provide alternate if not available or incorrect 
               (using Ternary Operator). Change or remove as you see fit.          */
            // Must have at least two characters in Name otherwise "UNKNOWN" is provided:
            String name = studentInfo[0].matches(".{2,}") ? studentInfo[0] : "UNKNOWN";
            // Must have at least two characters in Country name otherwise "UNKNOWN" is provided:
            String address = studentInfo[1].matches(".{2,}") ? studentInfo[1] : "UNKNOWN";
            // Must be a Integer number (only digits) otherwise -1 is provided:
            int id = studentInfo[2].matches("\\d+") ? Integer.parseInt(studentInfo[2]) : -1;
            // Must be a Integer number (only digits) otherwise -1 is provided:
            int grade = studentInfo[3].matches("\\d+") ? Integer.parseInt(studentInfo[3]) : -1;
            // Must be available and Must be a Integer number (only digits) otherwise -1 is provided.
            int age = studentInfo.length == 5 && studentInfo[4].matches("\\d+") ? Integer.parseInt(studentInfo[4]) : -1;
            
            // Add student to students linked list.
            students.add(new Student(name, address, id, grade, age));
        }
    }
}
```

To use the above method might be something like this:

```
String fileName = "/Users/noor/NetBeansProjects/student_file.txt";
try {
    readStudentsFromFile(fileName);
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    // Handle the exception (if any) the way you want).
    System.out.println("readStudentsFromFile() Method Error!\n" + ex);
}

// Display List of Students:
for (Student std : students) {
    // The Student class was supplied A toString() method:
    System.out.println(std.toString());
}
```

The **Student** class might look something like this:

```
public class Student {
        
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private int id;
    private int grade;
    private int age;

    public Student(String name, String address, int id, int grade, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.id = id;
        this.grade = grade;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + "\t" + address + "\t" + id + "\t" + grade + "\t" +  age;
    }
        
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(int grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am so grateful to you, your answer solved My problem and my project has become working. @DevilsHnd